# How do I validate Start and End Dates by column?

Tags: column, validation

I have a site where employees input schedule items, each with a Start Date and End Date.  I would like an error message to appear when users select an End Date before the Start Date.  What formula can I use under Column Validation settings so that the user has to choose an End Date that is greater than or equal to the Start Date column?

I have already done this in the List Validation Settings, but I would like to validate by column so that the error message appears by the End Date field rather than at the bottom of the form.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PreSaveAction to validate the date fields on your forms.

In PreSaveAction() function, you can write your custom javascript and validate that End Date should be equal or greater than the Start date.

[How to use PreSaveAction](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/86fe14fc-f353-4521-bf88-fd7fcabaa768/using-presaveaction-in-newformaspx-in-sharepoint-list).